# Something wrong in trying to upload my rails application in digitalocean using 1 click ruby on rails installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean

I've struggling how to deploy rails app in digital ocean. This is my first time to deploy an app especially in digital ocean. I already change my app folder name into rails which is the default application when you install the droplet then change the default with the old_rails ( folder name ) .. I already follow your tutorial in installing rails with 1 click but when I browse my IP address it gave white page, nothing was on display.

I access the `/home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log`

```
E, [2015-03-03T14:02:10.631045 #1030] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
E, [2015-03-03T14:02:10.631336 #1030] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:576:in `process_client'
E, [2015-03-03T14:02:10.631587 #1030] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:670:in `worker_loop'
E, [2015-03-03T14:02:10.631835 #1030] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:525:in `spawn_missing_workers'
E, [2015-03-03T14:02:10.632101 #1030] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
E, [2015-03-03T14:02:10.632346 #1030] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2015-03-03T14:02:10.632590 #1030] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
E, [2015-03-03T14:02:10.632788 #1030] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
E, [2015-03-03T14:02:10.633043 #1030] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
E, [2015-03-03T14:02:10.633314 #1030] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
E, [2015-03-03T14:02:56.881239 #1038] ERROR -- : app error: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)`
```

I already configured the secretkeybase error but nothings happen .. I'm in 2 days trying to deploy this app .. Hoping for a help. :)

Updated

config/secret.yml

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 44407ec69rt1f712c198bxcvafd1441235eda59ff561ec395b694b55269a6c00dad95788950e659568

test:
  secret_key_base: 6eff1b64b66ddbff2431fadfad1a3e4abf23f305482711a3c8801505f74bae79b04c600aa9a5b38
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["9a6eb637930b970f496e8b0fd8f9ed4b70bdb2c23c666398906ff9ba24a387efa3164"] %>
```

echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE

```
2275cfklj828d7e096152cadcc576f80687aebe9bbb7ddxcsd2ea3f7ba4ffc7ce342opad0b213f92b8deca61b657d3dfcvbcvedc2f834c77adf52048f507cdfe3d9c064e054a2159c
```

Comment: Can you provide your `config/secrets.yml`? Seems like it has invalid format or any other mistake.

Comment: Can you confirm that `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE` returns a value on your server?

Comment: Hi, Updated the question with the config/secrets.yml and echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE .. Thank you!

Comment: Your `config/secret.yml` file sets production's `secret_key_base` to the value of the environment variable `9a6eb6379...`. I doubt this is what you want, you should set `secret_key_base` to the value of itself without using `<%= ENV["..."] %>`.

Comment: Also, please do not post your secret key bases on the public Internet, it will leave your application more vulnerable to attack. You should generate new secret key bases for all of your environments. Don't post those on Stack Overflow or anywhere else on the public Internet, and try to store them all in environment variables instead of files if possible.

Comment: That was not the original sir. I already do something in that key. Thank you for your advice. :D

Answer (score 0):

Probably you made a typo, but

```
config/secret.yml
```

should be named

```
config/secrets.yml
```

BTW, you are using following ENV var

```
<%= ENV["9a6eb637930b970f496e8b0fd8f9ed4b70bdb2c23c666398906ff9ba24a387efa3164"] %>
```

probably you should try instead of it

```
<%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>
```

Comment: So, where should I put the generated key secret ? I thought I put the secret key in <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>

Comment: No, ENV['something'] refers to environment variable in Unix-based systems.

It can be set multiple ways. during command run "SECRET_KEY_BASE=some_secret rails server"
Or in users .bash_profile
Or checkout dotenv ruby gem